# additional Total row to output MDX

Tags: mdx

How I can get additional Total row to output from following MDX:

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Internet Gross Profit]
   ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[Customer].[City].[City] * [Product].[Product].[Product]} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  (
    [Date].[Fiscal Weeks].[Fiscal Year].&[2007]
   ,[Employee].[Employee Department].[Employee].&[105]
  );
```

as I can get from pure SQL. Here is SQL aggregation analog

```
select 
    [Customer].[City].[City],[Product].[Product].[Product]
    , sum([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]) as [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    , sum([Measures].[Internet Gross Profit]) as [Measures].[Internet Gross Profit]
    , sum([Measures].[Sales Amount]) as [Measures].[Sales Amount]
from  [Adventure Works]
where   [Date].[Fiscal Weeks].[Fiscal Year].&[2007] and [Employee].[Employee Department].[Employee].&[105] 
group by [Customer].[City].[City],[Product].[Product].[Product]

union 

select 
    'Total'  ,null 
    , sum([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]) as [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    , sum([Measures].[Internet Gross Profit]) as [Measures].[Internet Gross Profit]
    , sum([Measures].[Sales Amount]) as [Measures].[Sales Amount]
from  [Adventure Works]
where   [Date].[Fiscal Weeks].[Fiscal Year].&[2007] and [Employee].[Employee Department].[Employee].&[105]
```

Answer (score 1):

Danylo's answer may not be the perfect approach:

1. It errors. He uses the following : `[Customer].[City].[All] * [Product].[Product].[All]` which is trying to crossjoin members but he needs to explicitly make these single member sets: `{[Customer].[City].[All]} * {[Product].[Product].[All]}`
2. From what I've read `NonEmptyCrossJoin` is a remnant of the past and best to avoid: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2006/10/09/mdx-nonempty-exists-and-evil-nonemptycrossjoin.aspx
3. If I make the correction detailed in 1 the script only returns 1 row which I assume is not what is required?

I'd just add a tuple using the All members like this:

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Internet Gross Profit]
   ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      (
        [Customer].[City].[All]
       ,[Product].[Product].[All]
      )
     ,{[Customer].[City].[City] * [Product].[Product].[Product]}
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  (
    [Date].[Fiscal Weeks].[Fiscal Year].&[2007]
   ,[Employee].[Employee Department].[Employee].&[105]
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need an extra single All members output?

```
Select 
{
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
    [Measures].[Internet Gross Profit],
    [Measures].[Sales Amount]
} on 0,
{
    [Customer].[City].[All] *
    [Product].[Product].[All]
    +
    NonEmptyCrossJoin( 
        [Customer].[City].[City].Members,
        [Product].[Product].[Product].Members,
        2
    ) 
} on 1
From [Adventure Works]
Where 
(
    [Date].[Fiscal Weeks].[Fiscal Year].&[2007],
    [Employee].[Employee Department].[Employee].&[105]
)
```

By the way, there is [advanced grouping within MS SQL server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx). Also your may find [this article](http://blog.soft-prestidigitation.com/the-totals-and-the-nonemptycrossjoin-function.html) useful in order to understand the MDX cross-joining.